# Bash: How do I split strings?

Tags: string

I have this text file with lines that I need to split hopefully using parameter expansion:
For example this line:

```
'A  B'
```

needs to be:

```
A
B
```

They are separated by \t instead of \n. For \n, I was trying to experiment with:
foo=$'A\nB - (T)'; echo "${foo//'\n'/$'\n'}"
And it worked.

But for \t it is not working if I substitute \n by \t above.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

I tried:

```
foo=$'A B'; echo "${foo//'\t'/$'\t'}"
```

To expect:

```
A
B
```

Comment: `tr '\t' '\n' < file.tsv`?

Comment: Try `printf '%s\n' "${foo/$'\t'/$'\n'}"`.  (`echo` doesn't work in general so I replaced it with `printf`.)

Comment: Your code works for me when  rather than using `\t` in the `foo=` string, I use the `vi` mode editing and replace `\t` with `^V^I` , meaning `Ctrl-VCtrl-I`. (or a literal tab char, you can also press the `<TAB>` key, rather that `^I`). ...... `^V` *escapes" the following value in CLI processing. Good luck.

Comment: @pjh Thanks! I also tried that with output redirection to the text file and printf actually worked for that instead of echo!

Comment: Thanks to the other solutions as well, tr works as well but printf with param expansion was the simplest with output redirection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They are separated by \t instead of \n. For \n, I was trying to
> experiment with: foo=$'0-1 Months\nIT Basics - (T)'; echo
> "${foo//'\n'/$'\n'}" And it worked.
>
> But for \t it is not working if I substitute \n by \t above.

That produced the expected output because newline was in the source string from the beginning -- no substitution was done.  (Try `foo=$'0-1 Months\nIT Basics - (T)'; echo "$foo"`.)

Nevertheless, this minor variation will work for replacing tabs with newlines:

```
foo=$'0-1 Months\tIT Basics - (T)'; echo "${foo//$'\t'/$'\n'}"
```

Note the use of a C-escaped string to express a replacement pattern containing a single tab character, whereas your version attempts to use an ordinary single-quoted string.

Comment: echo "${foo//$'\t'/$'\n'}" works, replaces all the inputs with \t to \n when output redirected to the file and uses param expansion. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For that, I would use translate characters command (tr). Here an example:

```
foo=$(echo -e '0-1 Months\tc0-1 Months')
tr '\t' '\n' <<<"$foo"
```

Comment: (He specifically asked for a parameter substitution/expansion method) . (Just saying). Good luck to all.